# Strange Issue with Open With Explorer in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, open-with-explorer

I have two webapplication on my SharePoint 2013 server. For one webapplication I get below error when I try to open document library using open with explorer view.

[image]

Where on another webapplication on same server, the open with explorer view opens without any issue.

Both the applications are added in trusted setting with automatic logon with current username and password.

What can be problem with first webapplication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried populating (on the clients)

SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters

with your other app server FQDNs?

Add new Multi-String Value named 
AuthForwardServerList

Fill in data, for example:

```
https://*.Contoso.com
http://*.dns.live.com
*.microsoft.com
https://172.169.4.6
```

Details:

[KB943280 - Group policy solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b26d9599-9a70-4f44-b19d-08b3a42669f2/kb943280-group-policy-solution?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

[Prompt for Credentials When Accessing FQDN Sites From a Windows Vista or Windows 7 Computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943280/prompt-for-credentials-when-accessing-fqdn-sites-from-a-windows-vista-or-windows-7-computer)

Comment: Hi Igors, both webapplications are on same server.

Comment: But they surely have different URLs. You can try to include them into the above registry key.

Comment: Also, MS recommends, if you use different URLs on the same application server to include them into hosts file, as well as ensure that your bindings in IIS are correct for the problem web site.

Comment: I will try and let you know